# Drupal 7 make url alias accept additional args

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-path-aliases

I have node with path '**node/78**' and it has alias '**the-island/news**'.
In '**node/78**' path I can add additional args like '**node/78/second/third**', but if add in alias '**the-island/news/second/third**' it doesn't work. How create such aliases?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Pathauto module?
https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

Comment: This paths are made by it. I use module **subpathauto** to solve this problem, but I hoped that this problem can be solved without another big module.